# resetting the textbox through client side using javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to reset the text box through client side using javascript. I used following ways to reset the textbox. But, they are not resetting.

```
cText = "";
document.getElementById("<%=txtText.ClientID %>").value = cText;
```

and

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtText.ClientID %>").value = "";
```

Please can anyone help me in this?

code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            var cText = document.getElementById('<%=txtText.ClientID %>').value;

            if (cText != "") {
                alert("Text is not null.");
                document.forms['UserMaster'].elements['txtText'].focus();
                $("#<%=txtText.ClientID %>").val("");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" runat="server">
    <div class="page">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <br/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Font-Bold="true" OnClientClick="return validate()" 
                ForeColor="#9370DB" Height="23px" Width="65px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
                />
            <br />
   </div>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typo: `getElemenyById` should be `getElementById`.

Comment: @RGraham, thank you for correction,i didn't see that.

Comment: I tried with     $("#txtText").val("");. But it did not work.

Comment: how about this one : document.getElementById('<%=txtText.ClientID %>').innerText='';

Comment: how about $("#<%=txtText.ClientID %>").val("");

Comment: Even document.getElementById('<%=txtText.ClientID %>').innerText=''; and $("#<%=txtText.ClientID %>").val(""); is not working. I will post the code.

Comment: I have posted the code.

Comment: you dont have jquery in your code

Comment: I am not using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for your issues:

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtText.ClientID %>').value='';
```

you were using double quotes which was not working for you, whereas you need to use single quotes as show in the above code. This was your issues.

```
.value=" ";   //is Wrong
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and using this helped me solve the issue.
Here you can inspect the control from the browser and get the ID of that control.

```
// ControkClientID is the ID from Inspect element
document.getElementById(ControlClientID).value='';
```